# Debug error :java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.List

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Every time I click on a profile in my application, it causes this crash and error and I wanted to know why and try to find it.

The error:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.List
        at com.example.soulforge.fragments.Profile.lambda$loadBasicData$4$Profile(Profile.java:274)
        at com.example.soulforge.fragments.-$$Lambda$Profile$KwoPqF2dchhRaWfrPFWRwwexTfQ.onEvent(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(DocumentReference.java:504)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference$$Lambda$3.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(AsyncEventListener.java:42)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

The part of the profile that causes the issue

```java
followersList = (List<Object>) value.get("followers");
followingList = (List<Object>) value.get("following");
```

and the whole profile.java

```java
public class Profile extends Fragment {

    boolean isMyProfile = true;
    String uid;
    String userUID;
    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<PostImageModel, PostImageHolder> adapter;
    private TextView nameTv, toolbarNameTv, statusTv, followingCountTv, followersCountTv, postCountTv;
    private CircleImageView profileImage;
    private Button followBtn;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayout countLayout;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private ImageButton editProfileBtn;
    List<Object> followersList, followingList, followingList_2;
    boolean isFollowed;
    DocumentReference userRef, myRef;

    public Profile() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        init(view);

        myRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users")
                .document(user.getUid());

        if (IS_SEARCHED_USER) {
            isMyProfile = false;
            userUID = USER_ID;

            loadData();
        } else {
            isMyProfile = true;
            userUID = user.getUid();
        }

        if (isMyProfile) {
            editProfileBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            followBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            countLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            editProfileBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            followBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            countLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        userRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users")
                .document(userUID);

        loadBasicData();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3));

        loadPostImages();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        clickListener();
    }

    private void loadData() {
        myRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.e("Tag_b", error.getMessage());
                    return;
                }
                if (value == null || !value.exists()) {
                    return;
                }
                followingList_2 = (List<Object>) value.get("Following");
            }
        });
    }

    private void clickListener() {
        followBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (isFollowed) {
                followersList.remove(user.getUid());
                followingList_2.remove(userUID);

                final Map<String, Object> map_2 = new HashMap<>();
                map_2.put("following", followingList_2);

                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("followers", followersList);

                userRef.update(map).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        followBtn.setText("Follow");

                        myRef.update(map_2).addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
                            if (task1.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "UnFollowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Log.e("Tag_3", task1.getException().getMessage());
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        Log.e("Tag", "" + task.getException().getMessage());
                    }
                });
            } else {
                followersList.add(user.getUid());
                followingList_2.add(userUID);

                Map<String, Object> map_2 = new HashMap<>();
                map_2.put("following", followingList_2);

                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("followers", followersList);

                userRef.update(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            followBtn.setText("UnFollow");
                            myRef.update(map_2).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Followed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        Log.e("Tag", " " + task.getException().getMessage());
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Log.e("Tag", "" + task.getException().getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        editProfileBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(requireContext(), Profile.this);
        });
    }

    private void init(View view) {
        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        assert getActivity() != null;
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        nameTv = view.findViewById(R.id.nameTv);
        toolbarNameTv = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbarNameTV);
        statusTv = view.findViewById(R.id.statusTv);
        followersCountTv = view.findViewById(R.id.followersCountTv);
        followingCountTv = view.findViewById(R.id.followingCountTv);
        postCountTv = view.findViewById(R.id.postCountTv);
        profileImage = view.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        followBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.followBtn);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        countLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.countLayout);
        editProfileBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_profileImage);

        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    }

    private void loadBasicData() {
        userRef.addSnapshotListener((value, error) -> {
            if (error != null) {
                Log.e("Tag_0", error.getMessage());
                return;
            }
            assert value != null;
            if (value.exists()) {
                String name = value.getString("name");
                String status = value.getString("status");

                String profileURL = value.getString("profileImage");

                nameTv.setText(name);
                toolbarNameTv.setText(name);
                statusTv.setText(status);

                followersList = (List<Object>) value.get("followers");
                followingList = (List<Object>) value.get("following");

                followersCountTv.setText("" + followersList.size());
                followingCountTv.setText("" + followingList.size());

                try {
                    Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext())
                            .load(profileURL)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person)
                            .timeout(6500)
                            .into(profileImage);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (followingList.contains(userUID)) {
                    followBtn.setText("UnFollow");
                    isFollowed = true;
                } else {
                    isFollowed = false;
                    followBtn.setText("Follow");
                }
            }
        });

        postCountTv.setText("" + LIST_SIZE);
    }

    private void loadPostImages() {
        DocumentReference reference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").document(userUID);
        Query query = reference.collection("Post Images");
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<PostImageModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<PostImageModel>()
                .setQuery(query, PostImageModel.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<PostImageModel, PostImageHolder>(options) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public PostImageHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.profile_image_items, parent, false);
                return new PostImageHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostImageHolder holder, int position, @NonNull PostImageModel model) {
                Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext().getApplicationContext())
                        .load(model.getImageUrl())
                        .timeout(6500)
                        .into(holder.imageView);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            Uri uri = result.getUri();

            uploadImage(uri);
        }
    }

    private void uploadImage(Uri uri) {
        StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");

        reference.putFile(uri)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            reference.getDownloadUrl()
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                            String imageURL = uri.toString();
                                            UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder request = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder();
                                            request.setPhotoUri(uri);

                                            user.updateProfile(request.build());
                                            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                                            map.put("profileImage", imageURL);
                                            map.put("date", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

                                            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users")
                                                    .document(user.getUid())
                                                    .update(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    else
                                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private static class PostImageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView imageView;

        public PostImageHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this happening ,and why is it a `Long` instead of being a list and causing all this issues?

Comment: check you are getting right key for lists you might getting followers count instead of list

Comment: I've checked and ran in debug mode but i have been getting null for followers count for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the data is of Long class and you are trying to cast it to List

What you should try is

```
Map<String, Object> followerMap= new HashMap<>();
followerMap= value.getData();
assert followerMap!= null;

for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : followerMap.entrySet()) {
    long following= e.getValue();
    
    followingList_2 .add(following);
}
```